# React hooks - setInterval: causing the render to start before state is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I'm having an issue using React Hooks, specifically when I'm trying to run "setInterval". Currently my application has 2 buttons, "Next" and "Play".

When "Next" is clicked: the function "onNext" function runs, and the application renders.

When I click "Play": the function "onPlay" function is ran, but the component renders before the state has updated. I believe the "setInterval" is messing up the timing, but I'm not sure how to fix it or cause the component to wait to render until state is updated.

My initial thought is to use "useEffect", but I don't know how to make it tie into the "Play" button (since you can't place "useEffect", or any hooks within a function). I did try:

```
useEffect(() => {setInterval(() => {onNext();}, 500)}), [state3D]}
```

but this caused it to start running when the app is open. Any thoughts on how to set this up better?

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ThreePointVis from "./ThreePointVis.jsx";
// import ThreePointVis_Tut from "./ThreePointVis_Tut.jsx";
import Controls3D from "./Controls3D.jsx";
import Settings3D from "./Settings3D.jsx";

import {
  createWorld,
  create3DWorld,
  nextGen,
  randomFill,
} from "../files/game3D.jsx";
import { loadPreset } from "../files/presets3D.jsx";

import "./styles3D.css";

import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ThreePointVis from "./ThreePointVis.jsx";
// import ThreePointVis_Tut from "./ThreePointVis_Tut.jsx";
import Controls3D from "./Controls3D.jsx";
import Settings3D from "./Settings3D.jsx";

import {
  createWorld,
  create3DWorld,
  nextGen,
  randomFill,
} from "../files/game3D.jsx";
import { loadPreset } from "../files/presets3D.jsx";

import "./styles3D.css";

export const Game3D = (props) => {
  const [state3D, setState3D] = useState({
    // world3D: loadPreset("line"),
    world3D: loadPreset("plane"),
    generation: 0,
    isPlaying: false,
    colorStyle: "default",
  });

  const changeState = (props) => {
    // console.log("3d changestate: ", props);
    const { world3D, generation } = props;
    setState3D({ ...state3D, world3D: world3D, generation: generation });
  };

  const onChange = (world) => {
    // console.log("onChange: ", world);
    changeState({ world3D: world, generation: state3D.generation + 1 });
  };

  const onPlay = () => {
    console.log("3D onPlay: ", state3D.world3D);
    setState3D({ ...state3D, isPlaying: true });
    setInterval(() => {
      onNext();
    }, 500);
  };

  const onNext = () => {
    // console.log("onNext: ", state3D.world3D);
    onChange(nextGen(state3D.world3D));
  };

  const onStop = () => {
    console.log("onStop...");
    setState3D({ ...state3D, isPlaying: false });
    clearInterval();
  };

  const onSettingStyle = (settings, rules) => {
    // console.log("onsettings: ", settings, rules);
    const { colorStyle, gridSize, preset, generationSpeed } = settings;
    setState3D({
      ...state3D,
      world3D: loadPreset(`${preset}`),
      generation: generationSpeed,
      colorStyle: `${colorStyle}`,
    });
  };

  const onShuffle = () => {
    changeState({ world3D: randomFill(state3D.world3D), generation: 0 });
  };

  const onClear = () => {
    changeState({ world3D: createWorld(), generation: 0 });
  };

  // console.log("state3D:", state3D);
  return (
    <div className="container-3D">
      <Settings3D isPlaying={state3D.isPlaying} load={onSettingStyle} />
      <div className="vis-container">
        <ThreePointVis world={state3D.world3D} />
      </div>
      <Controls3D
        isPlaying={state3D.isPlaying}
        play={onPlay}
        next={onNext}
        stop={onStop}
        shuffle={onShuffle}
        clear={onClear}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use react Life cycle methods to synchronize view instead of using set intervals. You can use componentDidMount() which can be used to set your state. I recommend reading this https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I was hoping to use hooks but I guess this might be a situation where a class is better than hooks. I ended up having to convert this component into a class, which means React Hooks weren't possible.